Visual Studio Startup error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed with The specified module could not be found Error
I have installed Visual studio 2019 Enterprise Edition on my machine.
I have started experiencing an issue of VS getting restarting periodically.(like in every 5 mins)
Then I followed the solution suggested in Here
After that now I get the attached error every time I start Visual studio.
VS Startup error
And also VS getting restarting periodically as same as previously.
Also below error appears in the ActivityLog.xml file.
<entry>
    <record>164</record>
    <time>2024/06/20 13:50:26.030</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio Common IDE Package]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.PreviewFeatures.UsePreviewSdk.IsPreviewChannel()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.PreviewFeatures.UsePreviewSdk.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.CommonIDEStatics.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.BasePackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__6.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.CommonIDEPackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__20.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass20_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.&lt;WithCancellationSlow&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.&lt;JoinAsync&gt;d__76.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.Join(CancellationToken cancellationToken)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.Join(CancellationToken cancellationToken)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass36_1`1.&lt;AsVsTask&gt;b__3()</description>
    <guid>{6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}</guid>
    <hr>8007007e</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>165</record>
    <time>2024/06/20 13:50:26.033</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Common IDE Package]</description>
    <guid>{6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}</guid>
    <hr>8007007e</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>

I have tried Restarting windows, Repair in visual studio installer
and Uninstalling visual studio/visual studio installer and reinstalling. But no success. Any suggestions ?
I'm doubt something happened after deleting registry keys as mention in the link above
